# What's wrong with the derived Foldable instance of my KdTree?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to derive a Foldable instance for my `KdTree` data structure. The problem happened when I tried to make a `toList` function.

```
toList :: KdTree BBox3 a -> [(BBox3,a)]
toList t = F.foldr (:) [] t
```

when trying to compile, I got this error

```
Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘(BBox3, a)’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for toList :: KdTree BBox3 a -> [(BBox3, a)]
      at Data/Trees/KdTree/Regions/KThree/KThreeTree.hs:127:13
Expected type: KdTree BBox3 (BBox3, a)
  Actual type: KdTree BBox3 a
Relevant bindings include
  t :: KdTree BBox3 a
    (bound at Data/Trees/KdTree/Regions/KThree/KThreeTree.hs:128:10)
  toList :: KdTree BBox3 a -> [(BBox3, a)]
    (bound at Data/Trees/KdTree/Regions/KThree/KThreeTree.hs:128:3)
In the third argument of ‘foldr’, namely ‘t’
In the expression: foldr (:) [] t
```

I figured this was because the Foldable instance wasn't being derived correctly, so I made a spike to see what code was being generated.
But here's the thing, my spike worked. I added a `toList` function, with no complaint, and I can't figure out what made the difference. So, ultimately,
I would appreciate a clue as to how to either write a Foldable for my `KdTree BBox a`, or some insight in what is going wrong in my code compared to the correct (but seemingly the same) code in my spike.

Below is the spike, plus a link to my project code.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, InstanceSigs, DeriveFoldable, DeriveFunctor #-}

import Data.List
import qualified Data.Foldable as F

data BBox3 = BBox3 {
   v3x :: Double
 , v3y :: Double
 , v3z :: Double 
}

data AxisX = AxisX
data AxisY = AxisY
data AxisZ = AxisZ

class ( Bounded bbox) => KdTreeRegional bbox where

  data Axes bbox :: *
  data KdTree bbox :: * -> *
  data Leaf bbox :: * -> *

  toList :: KdTree bbox a -> [(bbox,a)]

instance KdTreeRegional BBox3 where
  data Axes BBox3 = X AxisX | Y AxisY | Z AxisZ

  data KdTree BBox3 a
    = KdNode {
        kdLeft     :: KdTree BBox3 a
      , nodeBBox   :: BBox3
      , kdSplit    :: (Axes BBox3,Double)
      , overlapped :: [(BBox3, a)]
      , kdRight    :: KdTree BBox3 a
      }
    | KdLeaf (Maybe (Leaf BBox3 a))
    deriving (F.Foldable)

  data Leaf BBox3 a = Leaf {
         leafBBox :: BBox3
       , kdleaf   :: [(BBox3,a)]
       } deriving (F.Foldable)

  toList :: KdTree BBox3 a -> [(BBox3,a)]
  toList t = F.foldr (:) [] t
```

https://github.com/mlitchard/kdtree/blob/stack/Data/Trees/KdTree/Regions/Internal.hs

https://github.com/mlitchard/kdtree/blob/stack/Data/Trees/KdTree/Regions/KThree/KThreeTree.hs

Update: This doesn't compile. I was getting this error

```
 The IO action ‘main’ is not defined in module ‘Main’
```

which I interpreted as a `Warning`, and ignored. I added `main = undefined` and received the same error I have been getting all along.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foldr` aggregates the right-most type parameter of the foldable structure.

```
class Foldable t where
    foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
    -- ...
```

In this instance, `t ~ KdTree BBox3`. Your implementation of `toList` will produce a list of `a`s.

```
toList :: KdTree BBox3 a -> [a]
toList t = F.foldr (:) [] t
```

(This exact function already exists, by the way, in the `Data.Foldable` module.)

Given the way you've set up your system, with `KdTree` as an associated type, there's no way to use the `Foldable` (or even `Bifoldable`) machinery to extract `BBox3`s from a `KdTree BBox3`. Your code looks more complicated than it ought to be - what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to generalize a KdTree adapted to regions.

Comment: If what you say is true, why does my spike type check?

Comment: @MichaelLitchard It doesn't type check, at least not on my setup. I get the same error in the `toList` function.

Answer (score 0):

> So, ultimately, I would appreciate a clue as to how to either write a Foldable for my `KdTree BBox a`

The `toList` function looks like it should be:

```
toList :: KdTree BBox3 a -> [(BBox3,a)]
toList (KdLeaf Nothing) = []
toList (KdLeaf (Just leaf)) = kdleaf leaf
toList (KdNode node) = toList (kdLeft node) ++ toList (kdRight node) ++ overlapped node
```

and from that `foldr` is:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> KdTree BBox3 a -> b
foldr f z kdtree = foldr f z (toList kdtree)
```

Comment: I was trying to use foldr to write toList, but I'll take it! Thanks. :)

Comment: `foldr` looks ill-typed to me, since `toList` returns a list of pairs, and `f` does not work on pairs.